# Excel VBA - Delete Empty Rows between Specific Text and a Row with 6 Populated Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete the empty rows between a row that contains the text "Cable Length*" and a row that contains 6 populated cells. The sheet is protected so that the user cannot fill more than 4 cells in the rows between these two points. Because the sheet is protected I need to unprotect-delete-protect the sheet in order to delete. Bellow is my attempt at resolving this issue.

```
Sub Delete_Empty_Rows()
'BUG: It will not delete all of the empty cells. It will delete 2, but not the rest.

'Prevents screen flashing while the code is going
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
'To unprotect the sheet
 ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Something"

'Top Boundary of the range is determined by finding "Cable Length(ft)*"
Cells.Find(What:="Cable Length(ft)*", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

'Bottom Boundary of the range is determined by CountA > 5
Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveCell.EntireRow) > 5
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Activate
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveCell.EntireRow) = 0 Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Loop

'To protect the sheet
 ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Something"

'Re-enables screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Debug your code to see what happens: After you delete the first row, the ActiveCell is already set on the "next" row, but at the top of the loop you set it to the next row. As a result, you miss every second row.

Comment: Typically when you do something like delete rows, you want to step backwards.

Answer (score 0):

try

modify accordingly the search range

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim searchRange As Range, foundCell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, sdel As Long, edel As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Set the search range
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set searchRange = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    
    ' Find the cell with "Cable Length(ft)*"
    Set foundCell = searchRange.Find("Cable Length(ft)*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    
    ' If the cell is found
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    sdel = foundCell.Row + 1
    edel = sdel
        Do Until Application.CountA(ws.Rows(edel)) > 5
        edel = edel + 1
        Loop
    End If
    ws.Rows(sdel & ":" & edel - 1).Delete
End Sub
```